# Deck#shuffle and Deck#shuffle! doing the same thing

Tags: ruby, shuffle

I am writing a card game framework in Ruby, and I have found an issue. I made a shuffle method that would mix up the cards, and it works fine. But well I call Deck#shuffle instead of Deck#shuffle! it keeps the deck shuffled, which I don't want.

I also find it strange that when I add :riffle as an argument, then shuffle doesn't keep the deck shuffled which I want.

I would appreciate any help on how to prevent Deck#shuffle from modifying the deck. Thanks!

Here is my code (well part of it, I can post the rest if anyone needs me too):

```
class Deck

    def initialize
        @cards = []
        (1..4).each { |suit|
            (1..13).each { |rank|
                @cards << Card.new(rank, suit)
            }
        }
    end

    def size
        @deck.length
    end

    def shuffle!(type = :random, precision = 100)
        case type
        when :random
            @cards.shuffle!
        when :riffle, :farro
            i = 0
            first, second = cut
            @cards = []
            while size != 52
                pile = (i.even? ? first : second)
                if pile.empty?
                        pile = (pile == first ? second : first)
                end
                add_card(pile.pop)
                i += 1  if (1..precision) === rand(1..100)
            end
        else
            warn "Invalid shuffle method."
        end
    end

    def shuffle(type = :random, precision = 100)
        dup.shuffle!(type, precision)
    end

    def add_card(card)
        @cards << card
    end

end

deck = Deck.new
deck.shuffle

p deck.cards.map(&:to_a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Deck` class have an instance variable - `@cards` - which hold the cards. `@cards` is actually a reference to an array of cards.

You did not implement `Deck#dup` when you use it you use `Object#dup` which does a shallow copy - it copies all the instance variables as references. **It doesn't duplicate the instance variables!**

This means that The `dup`ed `Deck` holds **a different** `@cards` variable that refers to **the same** array as the original `Deck`'s `@cards`. When you `shuffle` it the same array is shuffled. It get's accessed via a different reference variable, but it's still the same array.

If you try a `:riffle` or `:farro` shuffling it won't affect the original object since those in these shuffle types you do `@cards = []`, which sets `@cards` to a new array.

Still, I'd say that even if you didn't have the `:random` type the implementation would still be wrong - because the separation of the new `@cards` from the old one should not be in `shuffle!` - it should be in `dup`!

So, what you need to override the `dup` method and make it duplicate `@cards`. You might also want to change `initialize` to support this:

```
def initialize(cards = nil)
    if cards
        @cards = cards
    else
        @cards = []
        (1..4).each { |suit|
            (1..13).each { |rank|
                @cards << Card.new(rank, suit)
            }
        }
    end
end

def dup
    Deck.new(@cards.dup)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `dup` on an object, [you are only creating a shallow copy of that object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-dup). What this means is that while you are getting a new `Deck` instance, both your original and this new `Deck` will reference the same `@cards` instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

This line...

```
dup.shuffle!(type, precision)
```

... is creating a shallow copy of the Deck object.

Although it has its own instance variable `@cards` that instance variable is in fact referencing the same object as the instance variable in the original object.